# Override positioning of all figures

Tags: macros, floats

I'm designing all the figures for a book and I wanted to be able to change the positioning `[hbtp]` of *all* of them with one macro/command. A solution in which I could override the existing positioning options would be even better. Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have not used the optional argument anywhere then you can define

```
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{hp}
\makeatother
```

and they will all act as if `[hp]` (I think `float` package has a wrapper declaration that does this without needing `@` commands)

Any figure that has an explicit optional argument such as `[b]` will over-ride this default unless you redefine `figure` to ignore its optional argument.

---

This will make all floats use `hp` ignoring optional arguments and any setting of `fps@...`

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@xfloat\@xfloat
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\old@xfloat{#1}[hp]}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. That last part is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. How could I redefine it to ignore the optional arguments?

Comment: @Majoko see update

Comment: @Majoko Could you please edit the requirement to override also positioning commands explicitly given with single floats into your question? This would make it easier for future readers of their question to figure out if it possibly provides a solution for their problem.